# R - Spatial Join Between SpatialPoints (GPS coordinates) and SpatialLinesDataFrame

Tags: r, point, line, spatial-join

I am working on a university project which combines data science and GIS. We need to find an open-source solution capable of obtaining additional information from a massive GPS coordinates dataset. Clearly, I cannot use any API with daily request limit.

Here you can find a sample of the dataset the Professor provided us:

```
longitude <- c(10.86361, 10.96062, 10.93032, 10.93103, 10.93212)        
latitude <- c(44.53355, 44.63234, 44.63470, 44.63634, 44.64559)
longlat <- data.frame(longitude, latitude)
ID <- seq.int(1, 10)
```

The first step was joining my `SpatialPoints` with a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` using `over()` of `rgeos`. The `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` was obtained through `getData('GADM', country='ITA', level=3)` of `rgeos`.
For this first accomplished task, the objective was to associate to each GPS coordinates the information about `City` and `Region` which they belong to.
An example of the result I was able to obtain is:

```
require(sp)
require(rgeos)
my_spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = longlat, data = ID, proj4string = CRS(" +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 "))
italy_administrative_boundaries_level3 <- getData('GADM', country='ITA', level=3)
result <- over(my_spdf, italy_administrative_boundaries_level3)[, c("NAME_0", "NAME_1", "NAME_2", "NAME_3")]
result$ID <- ID
print(result)
```

#### QUESTION

Now the stuff become tricky because I need to associate additional and deeper information like `road_name` and `road_type`.
This information are contained in the shapefiles created on OpenStreetMap and available at: download.geofabrik.de/europe/italy.html.
I loaded the shapefile in R obtaining a `SpatialLinesDataFrame`:

```
require(rgdal)
shapefile_roads <- readOGR(dsn = "./road", layer = "roads")
```

Then, I naively tried to apply the same technique as for joining `SpatialPoints` and `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`:

```
result <- over(my_spdf, shapefile_roads)
```

Clearly, the result is just `NA`. One possible reason that came into my mind was that the coordinates of `my_df` are not in the exact position of the `Lines` in `shapefile_roads`, therefore, I should need some kind of radius parameter. However, I am not really sure.

Can you suggest me the correct approach to perform this spatial join between my `SpatialPoints` and the attributes of the `SpatialLinesDataFrame` obtained from the `road_shapefile` of OpenStreetMap?

Please if something is not very clear do not hesitate to ask.